# eloquent relationships in laravel is not working for multiple rows

Tags: laravel

Table: **coupons**
[image]

Table **shop_category:**

[image]

Coupon Model:

```
use Model;
/**
 * Model
 */
class Coupon extends Model
{


    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'coupons';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    public $belongsTo  = [
        'category' => ['ItScholarBd\Api\Models\Category','key' => 'id']
    ];

}
```

Category Model:

```
use Model;
use Lang;

/**
 * Model
 */
class Category extends Model
{
    public $implement = ['@RainLab.Translate.Behaviors.TranslatableModel'];
    public $translatable = ['name'];

    /**
     * @var string The database table used by the model.
     */
    public $table = 'shop_category';

    /**
     * @var array Validation rules
     */
    public $rules = [
    ];
    public $attachOne = [
      'icon' => 'System\Models\File'
    ];
}
```

Now I want to get the coupons with category as follows:

```
 $records    =   \ItScholarBd\api\Models\Coupon::with(['category']);
```

But When I print the records as follows:

```
echo '<pre>';print_r($records->toArray()); exit;
```

It shows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [code] => FEAST50
            [discount] => 2
            [validity] => 2020-11-17 23:59:59
            [min_order] => 40
            [shop_category_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2020-11-07 17:13:40
            [updated_at] => 2020-11-07 17:13:40
            [category] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [code] => FEAST50
            [discount] => 2
            [validity] => 2020-11-17 23:59:59
            [min_order] => 40
            [shop_category_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2020-11-07 17:13:40
            [updated_at] => 2020-11-07 17:13:40
            [category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Shopping
                    [created_at] => 2020-10-20 16:05:05
                    [updated_at] => 2020-10-20 16:05:05
                )

        )

)
```

Why 'category' index of first element is empty as two rows of coupons table is identical? I am struggling to find the mistake but no luck. Any hints?

Comment: What is the foreign key on Coupon model?

Comment: shop_category_id

Comment: What happen if you add new row?

Comment: New raw added normally.

Comment: This can be happend for data mismatch. I suggest you to delete both record then insert new rows and try again

Answer (score 0):

```
public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'shop_category_id','id');

    }
```

Hi in model

```
public function coupon(){

        return $this->hasMany(Coupon::class);

    }
```

you can call Category

```
$coupons = Coupon::with('category')->get();
```